# O que tem de errado com esse meu código Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Estou tentando criar um projeto simples para fins de estudos mas estou sentindo dificuldades em conclui-lo. Estou usando a biblioteca **Pytube** para baixar videos, consigo baixar os vídeos mas não consigo mostra a barra de progresso do download e o tamanho do arquivo (vídeo) a ser baixado.

**Meu código é esse:**

```
from pytube import YouTube
from pprint import pprint
from pytube import utils
from pytube.models import *

#Pede url do vídeo
url_video = str(input("URL do vídeo: "))

#Instancia a Classe.
yt = YouTube(url_video)

#Mostra o título do video + formato e resolução
print("\nTitulo do vídeo: ", yt.filename)
print("Formatos e Resoluções")

#Vai percorrer a Classe yt.get_videos formatos do vídeo e o tipo.
for i in yt.get_videos():
        print(i)

formato = str(input("\nQuais dos formatos a cima você deseja baixar seu vídeo(ex: .mp4 .3gp ): "))
resolucao = str(input("Digite qual das resoluções existente no video que você deseja baixar(ex: 720p): "))

print("\nVocê deseja renomear o nome do vídeo? Caso você diga queira o vídeo sera salvo com o nome padrão.\n")

perg = int(input("(1-Sim / 2-Não): "))

if perg == 1:
    nome = str(input("Digite o nome: "))
    yt.filename = nome

video = yt.get(formato, resolucao)
caminho = str(input("Caminho(ex: /usuario/Downloads/)>> "))
video.download(caminho)
```

Dei uma lida na documentação da biblioteca e fui até os módulos **utils** e **models**.

**no módulo Utils diz o seguinte:**

```
Def  print_status ( progress , file_size ):
    -benzóico.
    Esta função - quando transmitida como `on_progress` para` Video.download` - imprime
    O progresso de download atual.
    Argumentos:
    Progress - O comprimento dos bytes atualmente baixados.
    File_size - O tamanho total do vídeo.
    -benzóico.
    % = Progresso *  100 . / File_size
    Status =  r " % 10d   [ % 3.2f %% ] "  % ( progresso, porcentagem )
    Status = status +  chr ( 8 ) * ( len (status) +  1 )
    print status,
```

**e no Models**:

```
def download(self, path=None, chunk_size=8*1024,
             on_progress=None, on_finish=None):
    """
    Downloads the file of the URL defined within the class
    instance.
    Keyword arguments:
    path -- Destination directory
    chunk_size -- File size (in bytes) to write to buffer at a time
                  (default: 8 bytes).
    on_progress -- A function to be called every time the buffer was
                   written out. Arguments passed are the current and
                   the full size.
    on_finish -- To be called when the download is finished. The full
                 path to the file is passed as an argument.
    """

    path = (normpath(path) + '/' if path else '')
    fullpath = '%s%s.%s' % (path, self.filename, self.extension)
    response = urlopen(self.url)
    with open(fullpath, 'wb') as dst_file:
        meta_data = dict(response.info().items())
        file_size = int(meta_data.get("Content-Length") or
                        meta_data.get("content-length"))
        self._bytes_received = 0
        while True:
            self._buffer = response.read(chunk_size)
            if not self._buffer:
                if on_finish:
                    on_finish(fullpath)
                break

            self._bytes_received += len(self._buffer)
            dst_file.write(self._buffer)
            if on_progress:
                on_progress(self._bytes_received, file_size)
```

mas mesmo assim lendo não compreendi muita coisa. Alguém pra me ajudar?

Comment: No primeiro `for` existe um erro de indentação, mas acredito que isso ocorreu apenas quando postou o código aqui, senão nem baixaria o vídeo.

Comment: Tente fazer `video.download(caminho, on_progress=utils.print_status)`

Comment: Me retorno esse erro:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\RaquelCristina\Desktop\Estudos - Python\Projetinhos\BaixarVideosYoutube.py", line 34, in <module>
    video.download(caminho, on_progress=utils.print_status)
  File "C:\dev\kivy\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\models.py", line 77, in download
    raise OSError("Conflicting filename:'{0}'".format(self.filename))
OSError: Conflicting filename:'teste'

Comment: `Conflicting filename:'teste'`. Parece que está tentando salvar um arquivo que já existe (com mesmo nome).

Comment: Agora foi, eu coloquei assim: video.download(caminho, on_progress=print_status)

Comment: Obrigado pelo força!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Veja a documentação da função `download`:

```py
"""
Downloads the file of the URL defined within the class
instance.
Keyword arguments:
path -- Destination directory
chunk_size -- File size (in bytes) to write to buffer at a time
              (default: 8 bytes).
on_progress -- A function to be called every time the buffer was
               written out. Arguments passed are the current and
               the full size.
on_finish -- To be called when the download is finished. The full
             path to the file is passed as an argument.
"""
```

Existe um parâmetro chamado `on_progress`, que é uma função que será chamada sempre que o *buffer* for gravado em disco. Esta função receberá dois parâmetros: o primeiro refere-se ao *status* atual da transferência e o segundo o tamanho total do arquivo.

A própria biblioteca já dispoem de uma função para isso, que é justamente a `print_status`, então basta você fazer o seguinte:

```
video.download(caminho, on_progress=print_status)
```

Se precisar de algo mais específico, você pode criar essa função manualmente:

```
def my_print_status (current, fullsize):
    print("Transferido {} de {}".format(current, fullsize))
```

Talvez será necessário a formatação dos parâmetros conforme a necessidade, mas a ideia é essa. A chamada de `download` seria:

```
video.download(caminho, on_progress=my_print_status)
```